# Unable to fetch api from rest api and get results in react

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch, flask-restful

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([{}]);
  const [resultstate, setResultState] = useState([{}]);

  function handleSubmit() {
    const uri = "/?${form.one}&${form.two}";
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { nodeName, name, value } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === "INPUT") {
      setState({ ...FormData, [name]: value });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(uri)
      .then((res) => res.join())
      .then((data) => {
        setResultState(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <state onChange={handleChange}>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Solute</legend>
          <input name="one" value={state.one} />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Solvent</legend>
          <input name="two" value={state.two} />
        </fieldset>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </state>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am building an app where the flask rest API takes two strings and gives a floating value as a prediction. Now I am trying to connect to the react app so that the predictions can be shown on a webpage.

Now I was able to fetch the URL but unable to get the prediction result using `useEffect`. can someone point out where I am doing wrong

I am getting error as `'uri' is not defined  no-undef`

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined uri as part of the state, it is defined in a function locally. Hence the error.

To resolve, you need to add it to the state.

```
const [uri, setUri] = useState('');
```

in handleSubmit, you can use the setUri() method to set the state.

uri will now be accessible as part of the App state.

Comment: Thanks @Kislaya Mishra Then i am getting ```res.join is not a function``` error

Comment: That is a separate issue. `res` will have the response from your api. `join()` function is an array function, but response in an http response object. Are you sure you dont want to do a join on `res.data`? I am just speculating, I am not sure what kind of data is being returned by the api.   The data returned by your api will be accessible using `res.data`.